# JSF View Param Issue while reading in GET URL

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF(Prime Faces 4.0 + Pretty Faces 3.3) `<f:viewParam name="text" value="#{bean.property}" />` tag to read the param value from the below GET URL.

[http://testdomain:8080/text-abc%26123]

But I am getting only `abc` into `bean.property`. It seems `%26` is getting converted into `&` before reading text value. How I can read value which has `%26` (i.e `&` character) from the GET param value?

Comment: That value doesn't represent a request parameter at all. Request parameters appear in the query string which is the part after the `?` separator character in an URL. Your URL however doesn't have a `?` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem isn't related to JSF at all, but you using *%26* as part of a query string parameter. You should first understand that %26 means `&` based on [Percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) used in URL encoding for [Query Strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

After knowing this, you **should not** pass any argument containing "%" directly on your query string. Looks like you have/need another way to sent the parameters to the site, like using [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) or another application that will encode the parameters in your query string properly.